# I have automation code configured in Jenkins.The first build successfully launches the browser,but second build encounters a NullPointerException

Tags: jenkins, nullpointerexception

I have automation code configured in Jenkins. The first build successfully launches the browser, but the second build encounters a NullPointerException. How can I resolve this issue?

same code working for my local mechine but only issue in jenkins how can i resolve this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.